# Installing a custom 'non-rpm' kernel in CentOS 6

Tags: centos, centos6, grub, linux-kernel, installation

I've built a custom kernel using kernel.org, it has no .rpm file. How do I manually:

1. Install the Modules to /lib/modules (`make moduleinstall` or something?)
2. Make the initial ramdisk
3. Update grub

I haven't seen any documentation on how to do this for CentOS.

Comment: You make this sound like you've done it for a reason ? Are you doing this just for kicks, or is it to solve an issue your seeing ? Normally the non rpm way of doing things leads to madness, tis all.

Comment: I need a kernel newer than 2.6.37 for TPROXY support.

Comment: Make that at least version 3.2.30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ```
   make modules
   make modules_install
   ```
2. `mkinitrd /boot/initrd-x.y.z.t.img x.y.z.t`
3. `make install`